# Как сделать, чтобы при открытии приложения, использующего google карты, отображалось текущее местоположение?

Tags: android

Нужна помощь в создании android-приложения, использующего карты google!
Как сделать, чтобы при открытии приложения отображалось текущее местоположение?

Comment: Метку надо ставить `android`, IDE AS не относится к вопросу. А по сути вопроса - вам надо получить координаты юзера. В доке гугла на этот счёт неплохо всё расписано. Добавьте в вопрос что именно вам там непонятно.

Comment: map:cameraTargetLat="-33.796923"
map:cameraTargetLng="150.922433"

Comment: они ставят фиксированные значения ширины и долготы, и при запуске приложения карта открывается в этих координатах. А как сделать так, чтобы открывалось на координатах пользователя?

Comment: Можете привести конкретный код как получить координаты и установить их при открытии приложения?

Answer (score 1):

Согласно официальной документации надо как-то так:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    protected Location mLastLocation;

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        Timber.d("onConnected");
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Timber.d("onConnectionSuspended: %s", i);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Timber.d("onConnectionFailed: %s", connectionResult);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Timber.d("onLocationChanged: %s", location);
        mLastLocation = location;
    }
}
```

Comment: Далее полученную координату применить к карте.

Comment: можно ссылку на эту документацию?

Comment: @Mikhail, вот, вроде, оно: https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html

Comment: еще такой вопрос, я получил координаты в методе
`private void showLocation(Location location) {
        if (location == null) {
            return;
        }
        location.getLatitude();
        location.getLongitude();

    }`
как теперь их применить к карте или к методу onMapReady?

Comment: я уже разобрался: использовать методы класса GoogleMaps