# Хочу написать приложение под Android

Tags: android, android-studio

При установленном приложении на нескольких устройствах и попадании их (устройств) на расстояние меньше, например, 10м друг от друга, производится графическое и звуковое оповещение.
Как подобное реализовать, идеи? 
Видимо, нужен удаленный сервер, куда будут отправляться координаты от приложений. Там будут они как-то сравниваться? 
Есть ли уже готовые решения?
Имею начальные знания в написании простеньких приложений на эту ОС.

Comment: 10 метров - слишком мало даже для GPS

Comment: Это для примера. Хорошо, а километр?

Comment: Посмотрите что-нибудь про Wi-FI p2p connections. С помощью своих wi-fi-передатчиков телефоны могут передавать данные на небольших расстояниях (50-100м в здании и 200м на улице) без подключения к интернету. Только не знаю, что там насчёт определения конкретного расстояния, но может вам подойдёт.

Comment: @YungBlade, нет, не подойдет, спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

1. Подписываетесь на получение события изменения координат.
2. Отправляете их на сервер.
3. Сервер проверяет, что разница между пришедшими и имеющими координатами других юзеров меньше к-л числа.
4. Если это так - отправляет пуш на нужные устройства.
5. Девайс ловит пуш и отображает уведомление/делает что угодно

Comment: Спасибо, а есть примеры реализации? Пока непонятен даже пункт 1. Или не осилю, нужно искать разработчика?

Comment: @Сергей, примеров реализации целиком - нет. Но тут, на сайте, есть примеры кода для всех пунктов. В общем, все нужные данные можно и в доках найти.

Comment: Зачем сервер если можно использовать Wifi P2P?

Comment: @Ник, не очень понял. Вы имеете в виду случай, когда девайсы в одной WiFi сети находятся? Если да, то, наверное, можно и без сервера, но это очень уж ограничивающий применение приложения случай

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, не обязательно в одной сети. Хоть в разных странах.

Comment: Просматривал вчера стартандроид на ютубе, так там уроки датированы 13-м годом. 100% наверняка сейчас не работающие. Да и в комментах народ пишет, что не работает. Может подскажете рабочие реализации для чайников? Хотя бы с определением координат и рисованием трека на карте. Для начала, чтоб освоиться. Чтоб в голове по ящикам распихать.

Comment: Реализации полные такие нигде не видел, но вот вам ответ с кодом вывода в логи изменений местоположения: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/687166/17609. Вообще, вся информация нужная в документации есть. Просто подключаете библиотеки и следуете документации. Просто то, что вы хотите - это приложение с 3 разными либами (отслеживание смены локации, отображение на карте, приём пушей с сервера) и ещё сервер, который общитывает данные и пуши шлёт. В рамках одного вопроса такое не описать.Вы можете попробовать задать по вопросу по каждому пункты отдельно. Но,повторюсь, всё в доках есть и примеров масса